# Why does the && operator not appear to work in Matlab/Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm playing around with some slightly modified Euler problems.  The following code:

```
a=(0:1:999);
b=a(mod(a,5) == 0)
```

Appears to do the right thing.  However with a slight modification:

```
a=(0:1:999);
b=a(mod(a,5) == 0 && mod(a,3) == 0)
```

I get

```
b=[](0x0)
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `&` instead of `&&`

The & operator performs an element-by-element AND between matrices, while the && operator performs a short-circuit AND between scalar values.